# Getting "invalid credentials" in Laravel using JWT

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, postman

My user model:

```
namespace Modules\Settings\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class Users extends Authenticatable
{
Protected $table="user";
// protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $fillable = ['id','username','password','user_status_type_id','client_id','created_userid'];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

In the controller I have:

```
 public function login(Authentication $request){
   $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');



    try {
        // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials);


        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

I have used Hash::make($data->password) when creating the user.When I test it in Postman I always get "invalid credential"

Comment: what exactly are you sending FROM postman?

Comment: username and password

Answer (score 1):

if you are using version 0.5.* and kept the default settings as per the documentation, the `JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)` part will look for the input values 'email' and 'passowrd' `$request->only('email', 'password');`
In your case you are using `$request->only('username', 'password');`